# Vaadin 14 with Bower Components: module not found error

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

My project uses Vaadin 14.4.9. I'm trying to create a chart and to do so I'm using an add-on ChartJS for Vaadin 10: (https://github.com/syndybat/Chartjs-for-vaadin-10).

I have added the required dependencies into my pom file; however when I run the project, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ../target/frontend/generated-flow-imports.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bower_components/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js' in 'C:\Users\[...]'
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't use screenshots, where text would do.  We can not search in
or copy from screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly this does not work anymore with Vaadin 14:

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/chartjs/discussions

Reply from the author Petr Šmejkal

> I no longer maintain this plugin. Test it and if you want I will grant
> you access to the repository.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `ChartJS for Vaadin 10+` uses webjars so it should still work with v14 as long as you run in compatibility mode.

For more information see [Compatibility mode](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/guide/upgrading/v10-13#compatibility-mode)